# Mod_rewrite not working on subdirectory on localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this folder system:

```
localhost/websites/2018/mywebsite
```

And there I have this file:

```
products.php
```

so the full route I type in my browser to access it is:

```
localhost/websites/2018/mywebsite/products.php
```

Now, I'm trying to use mod_rewrite to get this:

```
products.php?cat1=a&cat2=b&cat3=c
```

into this:

```
shop/a/b/c
```

So the full url would be:

```
localhost/websites/2018/mywebsite/shop/a/b/c
```

I tried putting the .htaccess in here:

```
localhost/websites/2018/mywebsite
```

with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^shop/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /products.php?cat1=$1&cat2=$2&cat3=$3 [L]
```

But when I go to

```
localhost/websites/2018/mywebsite/shop/
```

I get a 404. I think it has to do with the directory tree because when I upload it to the website (root directory) it works fine.

Edit: I tried using

```
RewriteBase localhost/websites/2018/mywebsite
```

And some variations but it didn't work. It threw 500 server error.

Comment: Have you tried using [RewriteBase](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/fr/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteBase) to set your base directory?

Comment: Yep, but it threw a 500 server error, I edited the question to add that.

Comment: You shouldn't put the `localhost` in it. What about with just `RewriteBase /websites/2018/mywebsite/`? Also, if it throws an HTTP 500 you should check the Apache logs to see the full reason.

Comment: If I try `RewriteBase /websites/2018/mywebsite/` it throws 404 but if I try `RewriteBase websites/2018/mywebsite/` it throws a 500 error and in the log says: RewriteBase: argument is not a valid URL

Comment: Have you tried `products.php` instead of `/products.php` …?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use `%{QUERY_STRING}` for this to work. Try something like the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cat1=(.+)&cat2=(.+)&cat3=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /shop/%1/%2/%3/? [R=301,L,NE]
```

This grabs each of your variables and then rewrites `/shop/a/b/c` onto the end of your URL. The use of `?` is there to stop the original query from appearing on the end of the URL.

Make sure you clear your cache ***before*** testing this.